# Incluir texto sobre direitos autorais ao copiar do site

Tags: javascript

Teria como a pessoa copiar um texto do meu site e, não importa onde ela colar, exiba o texto que ela copiou e uma mensagem de direitos autorais?

Achei muito conteúdo sobre como bloquear a cópia do conteúdo, não é isso que eu preciso, eu não tenho nada de código referente a isso, pois não sei como fazer ou se tem como fazer isso.

Comment: Dica: Por experiência própria, não adianta tentar bloquear seu código ou texto, de qualquer forma sempre é possível copia-lo, ou alguém vai conseguir fazer igual. Direitos Autorais independem de registro porém somente protegem um conteúdo na integra como visto na lei:
http://www.casadoautorbrasileiro.com.br/direito-autoral/nocoes-basicas

Comment: Botar um texto com o Logotipo Copyright para lei é meramente ilustrativo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aqui está o código JavaScript que acrescentará informações extras no texto da web copiado. Basicamente é criar um elemento DOM invisível e preenchê-lo com o código html copiado adicionando as informações extras.

[**Fonte**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026335/how-to-add-extra-info-to-copied-web-text/4777746#4777746)

```js
function addLink() {
    //Obtem o texto selecionado e acrescenta as informações extras
    var selection = window.getSelection(),
        pagelink = '<br /><br /> mensagem de direitos autorais: ' + document.location.href,
        copytext = selection + pagelink,
        newdiv = document.createElement('div');

    //esconder a div recém-criada
    newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';

    //insere a div, adiciona as informações extras e defina a nova seleção
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(newdiv);
    }, 100);
}

document.addEventListener('copy', addLink);
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam hendrerit orci vel urna tincidunt, id aliquet leo dapibus. Nunc sodales arcu auctor, aliquam augue ut, blandit lorem. Ut eleifend dui in interdum fringilla. Etiam eleifend, sem et varius ornare, massa tellus tincidunt metus, ac ultricies ex diam ac arcu. Pellentesque at scelerisque ex. Quisque lobortis lectus sit amet porttitor dapibus. Nunc eget sagittis enim. Aenean mollis rutrum ante. Etiam lacinia aliquam pellentesque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
<br>
<textarea placeholder="Cole aqui o texto copiado" rows="12" cols="52"></textarea>
```

Para incluir o titulo da página (`document.title`) nas informações extras:

```
pagelink = '<br /><br /> &copy; '+document.title+'<br /> mensagem de direitos ..................
```

---

---

Você pode  determinar a partir de que comprimento do texto selecionado deve exibir as informações extras. Basta adicionar no código essa linha

```
if (("" + selection).length < 30) return;
```

Código completo:

```
function addLink() {
    //Obtem o texto selecionado e acrescenta as informações extras
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    //se a seleção é curta não vamos incomodar nossos usuários
      if (("" + selection).length < 30) return;

     var  pagelink = '<br /><br /> mensagem de direitos autorais: ' + document.location.href + ' &copy; ' +document.domain,
        copytext = selection + pagelink,
        newdiv = document.createElement('div');

    //esconder a div recém-criada
    newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';

    //insere a div, adiciona as informações extras e defina a nova seleção
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(newdiv);
    }, 100);
}

document.addEventListener('copy', addLink);
```